# Python, extracting a string between two specific characters for all rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to write a function that will extract the string between 2 specific characters.

My data set contains emails only, that look like this: `pstroulgerrn@time.com`.

I am trying to extract everything after the `@` and everything before the `.` so that the email listed above would output `time`.

Here is my code so far :

```
new = df_personal['email'] # 1000x1 dataframe of emails

def extract_company(x):
        y = [ ]
        y = x[x.find('@')+1 : x.find('.')]
        return y

extract_company(new)
```

**Note :** If I change `new` to `df_personal['email'][0]` the correct output is displayed for that row.

However, when trying to do it for the entire `dataframe`, I get an error saying :

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: so ... and whats wrong? Pelase hardcode a `df` to make this a [mre]

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'
If I change new to new = df_personal['email'][0] it displays the correct output for that individual row, but when trying to do it for the entire 1000 row column, I get that error.

Comment: Use pandas' `str.find()` method for series instead: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.find.html

Comment: you can use ```apply``` to call for the function for every row separately. Your function as it currently written can work one row at the time

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a series of all matching texts using regex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( ['kabawonga@something.whereever','kabawonga@omg.whatever'])
df.columns = ['email']

print(df)

k =  df["email"].str.extract(r"@(.+)\.")

print(k)
```

Output:

```
# df
                           email
0  kabawonga@something.whereever
1         kabawonga@omg.whatever

# extraction
           0
0  something
1        omg
```

See [pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df_personal["domain"]=df_personal["email"].str.extract(r"\@([^\.]+)\.")
```

Outputs (for the sample data):

```py
import pandas as pd

df_personal=pd.DataFrame({"email": ["abc@yahoo.com", "xyz.abc@gmail.com", "john.doe@aol.co.uk"]})

df_personal["domain"]=df_personal["email"].str.extract(r"\@([^\.]+)\.")

>>> df_personal

                email domain
0       abc@yahoo.com  yahoo
1   xyz.abc@gmail.com  gmail
2  john.doe@aol.co.uk    aol
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an apply function, by first splitting by a `.` and then by `@` for each of the row:

Snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( ['abc@xyz.dot','def@qwe.dot','def@ert.dot.dot'])
df.columns = ['email']


df["domain"] = df["email"].apply(lambda x: x.split(".")[0].split("@")[1])
```

Output:

```
df
Out[37]: 
             email domain
0      abc@xyz.dot    xyz
1      def@qwe.dot    qwe
2  def@ert.dot.dot    ert
```